# Problem with Reading Huge Attachments using SOAP API

Tags: soap-api

Using the SOAP API and the WSC libraries I am having difficultly reading attachments larger than around 800-900MB, With gzip encoding the zip reader returns a "Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Corrupt GZIP trailer" exception. When doing the same without compression, the SAX parser indicates that the SOAP envelope is either corrupt or incomplete:

Caused by: java.io.EOFException: no more data available - expected end tags  to close start tag  from line 1 and start tag  from line 1 and start tag  from line 1 and start tag  from line 1 and start tag  from line 1 and start tag  from line 1, parser stopped on END_TAG seen ...... @1:286335571

Of course, this happens after many megabytes of the SOAP envelope have already been processed. Both protocol 34 and 37 exhibit the same behavior.

Two questions:
+ has this issue come up before (GB attachments must be fairly rare)?
+ what is a rational next step?